# Tuned-adm differences between Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04

Tags: 20.04, 22.04

I'd like to know why tuned profiles are different on Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04 as shown here.

[image: here].

I'd like to know is it safe to apply the 22.04 profile on 20.04 Ubuntu with creating the HPC profile or is there any special reason why on Ubuntu 20.04 this is created differently in Ubuntu 20.04?

I'm running a mission critical storage system and I've used the hpc profile on CentOS 8. I'd like to use this profile on Ubuntu 20.04 but it is not available. Also the latency-performance profile which is the base of the hpc is different compared to the 22.04, however the 22.04 tuned profiles are very similar to the tuned profiles on CentOS 8.